# Facebook URL Share :Default Wordpress Thumbnail for my website and thumbnail image for each post

Tags: facebook, html, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

Hi guys i developed this site:

http://viviendodiferente.mx/

It works awesome, but im currently having some troubles with facebook when you share the url it shows another image im not currently setting on my meta tags:

```
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://viviendodiferente.mx">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Viviendo Diferente">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Viviendo Diferente">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Viviendo Diferente bLOG">
    <meta property="og:type" content="Website">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.servervistadesarrollos.com/sites/viviendodiferente/wp-content/themes/viviendo2/images/logoViviendo2.jpg">
```

And when i debug it, it says:

Meta Tags In Body:  Your page has meta tags in the body instead of the head. This may be because your HTML was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree.
Please fix this in order for the tags to be usable.

Also when you like inside a post it keep showing a default image instead of the thumbnail.

Any ideas? I was using easy facebook share thumbnails but its just not working at all ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy and paste all meta tags inside the `<head>`

Sample:

```
<head>
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.servervistadesarrollos.com/sites/viviendodiferente/wp-content/themes/viviendo2/images/logoViviendo2.jpg"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="590102141003905"/>
    <title>Viviendo Diferente</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var template = 'http://viviendodiferente.mx/wp-content/themes/viviendo2';
        var total = 56;  
        //alert(total)
    </script>
    <script src="http://viviendodiferente.mx/wp-content/themes/viviendo2/js/jqueryeasing.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://viviendodiferente.mx/wp-content/themes/viviendo2/js/plugins.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://viviendodiferente.mx/wp-content/themes/viviendo2/js/isotope.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://viviendodiferente.mx/wp-content/themes/viviendo2/js/infinitescroll.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://viviendodiferente.mx/wp-content/themes/viviendo2/js/main.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://viviendodiferente.mx/wp-content/themes/viviendo2/style.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="http://viviendodiferente.mx/wp-content/themes/viviendo2/images/fviviendo.jpg">

<!--start facebook-->
<meta property="og:url" content="http://viviendodiferente.mx">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Viviendo Diferente">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Viviendo Diferente">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Viviendo Diferente bLOG">
    <meta property="og:type" content="Website">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.servervistadesarrollos.com/sites/viviendodiferente/wp-content/themes/viviendo2/images/logoViviendo2.jpg">

</head>
```

Comment: actually your answer is correct it worked i just decide to add extra code for the single.php Thanks!